# Complete HTML doesn't render when scraping using bs4 python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from geeksforgeeks for my own simple scraping and analysis project.

I am using `bs4` and `requests` - python2

I need to scrape all the questions on this url so I do,

```
ques_page = requests.get('https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/explore/?page=1')
ques_soup = BeautifulSoup(ques_page.text, 'lxml')
get_ques = ques_soup.find('div', class_="panel problem-block")
```

The class `panel problem-block` contians the question data.

But when I view the scraped `html` - `print(ques_page.text)` doesn't contain the `div` at all !

On viewing the page source ( Ctrl-F for `problemFeed` this div is where all the questions are present )

`<div id="problemFeed" class="row" data-masonry-options='{"itemSelector": ".item" }'></div>`

This `div` is EMPTY! Thus am not able to scrape any data out of it! How is this possible, since I can view everything inside this `div` in the console, but not in the page source or during scraping!

Comment: It is possible that this part is rendered after the page is up (by javascript) thus its not part of the original html

Comment: if you open this page in a browser like chrome and select "view page source" you will see this class "panel problem-block" doesn't exist either.

Comment: Yes, this class is inside the `problemFeed` div itself thats why @ChrisDoyle

Comment: @RonSerruya so such things are not scrap-able at all ?

Comment: You can scrape the rendered HTML using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io)

Comment: No you missed my point. Requests.get will just get you the html source code. However there are java script events which will then modify the DOM object after its loaded and add in content. Tracing in chrome shows that 81 nodes are added to the problemfeed div after the html is loaded. requests.get wont get these changes.

Comment: @Sreyas yes, got it!

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yeah right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it from the Ajax endpoint with post request

```
data = {'page': 1, 'query' : 'page1'} # 2, page2...
ques_page = requests.post('https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/ajax/practicePageAjax.php', data=data)
ques_soup = BeautifulSoup(ques_page.text, 'lxml')
get_ques = ques_soup.find('div', class_="panel problem-block")
print(get_ques)
```

Comment: you can view it on browser console